# Publish message from SNS to kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have requirement to publish messages from SNS to kinesis. I have found that, it is not possible directly by subscribing same as SNS/SQS. I will need to write lambda to fetch from SNS and publish it to kinesis. 
Is there any other way to publish records from SNS to kinesis directly? 
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazon SNS is a publish/subscribe model.

Messages sent to SNS can be subscribed from:

- `http/s`: delivery of JSON-encoded message via HTTP POST
- `email`: delivery of message via SMTP
- `email-json`: delivery of JSON-encoded message via SMTP
- `sms`: delivery of message via SMS
- `sqs`: delivery of JSON-encoded message to an Amazon SQS queue
- `application`: delivery of JSON-encoded message to an EndpointArn for a mobile app and device.
- `lambda`: delivery of JSON-encoded message to an AWS Lambda function.
- **Other options: See Otavio's answer below!**

See: [Subscribe - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html)

Of these, the only ones that could be used to send to Amazon Kinesis would be to use **AWS Lambda**. You would need to write a Lambda function that would send the message to a Kinesis stream.

To clarify: Your Lambda function will not "fetch from SNS". Rather, the Lambda function will be triggered by SNS, with the message being passed as input. Your Lambda function will then need to send the message to Kinesis.

Your only other alternative is to change the system that currently sends the message to SNS and have it send the message to Kinesis instead.

Comment: or you use EventBridge service https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/ just launched by AWS. Its supports Kinesis as subscriber

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, as the feature requested is now available in SNS: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/01/amazon-sns-adds-support-for-message-archiving-and-analytics-via-kineses-data-firehose-subscriptions/

Answer (score 6):

Good news! As of January 2021, Amazon SNS has added support for message archiving and analytics via Kinesis Data Firehose subscriptions. You can now load SNS messages into S3, Redshift, Elasticsearch, MongoDB, Datadog, Splunk, New Relic, and more. The SNS documentation has the details.